# how to output the mysqli_error message at during ajax calling while using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how to output or alert the mysqli error message during an ajax call?

here's my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['resumetitle']) || isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['dob']) || isset($_POST['gender']) || isset($_POST['cvid'])){
    $result =  $db->updatepdetails($_POST['resumetitle'],$_POST['name'],$_POST['dob'],$_POST['gender'],$_POST['cvid']);
    if($result){
      echo "success!";
    } else {
      echo "failed! ".$result->error;
    }
   }
```

//here's my js code

```
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "classes/ajax.resumeupdate.php",
      data: "resumeid="+cvid+"&resumetitle="+resumetitle+"&name="+name+"&dob="+dob+"&gender="+gender,
      success: function(msg){
        //window.location = "resumeview.php?cvid="+cvid;
        alert(msg);
      },
   });
```

after the ajax call, it only pop out the word "failed!" ...i wish to see the mysqli_error too, how's that?

Comment: Why not look in the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: At any rate, you need to add more detail about the `$db` class you are using - `updatepdetails` is not a method of the mysqli class, is it?

Comment: you're checking the content of $result and if it's false then you're trying to access $result->error? this will always echo false

Answer (score 0):

You use `$db->error` and not `$result->error`

Comment: even if i use $db->error, i only see "failed!" but the supposedly mysqli error message is not being appended..i also checked the error logs..nothing was written